# Adding Images to divs dynamically with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling adding one image to one div dynamically with jQuery.

```
var albumCoverPhotos = function (albumPhotoData) {
  var albumCoverArr = "";
  albums.forEach (function (el){
  albumCoverArr +=  "<img class= 'events-profilePic' src='" + el.albumCover +
      "' alt=''/>";
  });
  $('.album-image-container').append(albumCoverArr);
};
albumCoverPhotos(albums);
```

All the images are being displayedin each div, but I want each div to only hold one image. See screenshots below.
[SEE SCREENSHOT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjHfT.png)

Comment: Show html structure used. Also what does `albums` look like?

Comment: Where are the screenshots?  Can you include them in the post?

Comment: it's pretty basic. Just putting a new image in this div which is used 6 times:  
 <div class="album-image-container"> </div>

Comment: just added screenshots link

Comment: @wbhood basic or not, we are not telepaths. please post your code otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: will do @Banana I'm new to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Looks like you want to be dynamically creating the `div`s themselves, rather adding `img`s to existing ones

Comment: 'albums' is a list of data

Comment: I think that did it @Rhumborl . Thanks!

Comment: @wbhood Your `append()` adds an image to every element with class `album-image-container`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

We do not know the HTML environment which this code will hit. So we can only guess that the images are dislayed multiple times, because class `album-image-container` is assigned to several containers (`div`'s?).

You might also consider to construct the `img` tags using JQuery too:

```
albums.forEach(function(el) {
    $('.album-image-container').append(
        $('<img>')
            .addClass('events-profilePic')
            .attr({
                'src' : el.albumCover,
                'alt' : ''
            });
        )
});
```